# How to serve dynamic image server using node

Tags: node.js, image, express, dynamic

How can i serve the same image with dynamic sizes by passing query string using node API?

Example:

`https://localhost:3000/fish.jpg?quality=80&strip=all&w=1320`

Answer (score 1):

Well there are 2 options that I can think of.
You have to listen for GET '/' and do the following:

1. Have this photo saved in few resolutions and if the resolution match send it back to the client.
2. Use a package like `sharp` - https://github.com/lovell/sharp and transform an image as you want to and then send it back. It will be CPU heavy operation, keep it in mind.